Plotting daily line chart using TTM financials PineScript
Calculating Daily FCF Yield Indicator in TradingView Pine Script
I am trying to build an indicator that shows the daily moving value for FCF Yield.
FCF is calculated as:
Cash from Operating Activities - Capital Expenditures + Depreciation & Amortization - Change in Net Working Capital

The 4 variables above are only available in the TTM frequency range.
FCF Yield is calculated as:
FCF Yield = FCF/Enterprise Value
where Enterprise Value = Market Capitalization + Net Debt - Cash and Equivalents

The 3 variables (Enterprise Value, Net Debt, and Cash and Equivalents) are also only available in the TTM frequency range.
I have checked and it seems like only Market Capitalization can be plotted daily, using the formula:
Total Shares Outstanding (frequency: FQ) × Closing Price (available daily)

I want to get the FCF Yield results to be calculated daily and move according to the closing price on each of the candlesticks. Could anyone help me understand how to get this to be graphed daily, and not stopping at the last quarter?
Here's my current code:
//@version=5
indicator("TTM FCF Yield %", precision = 2, format = format.percent)

var frequency = "FQ"
int timeframeInSeconds = timeframe.in_seconds()
int totalSecondsIn12Months = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
var frequencyUnit = if frequency == "FY" 
    math.round(totalSecondsIn12Months / timeframeInSeconds)
else 
    math.round(totalSecondsIn12Months / timeframeInSeconds / 4)

fcf = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_F_OPERATING_ACTIVITIES", "TTM", barmerge.gaps_on)
enterpriseValue = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, 'ENTERPRISE_VALUE', frequency, barmerge.gaps_on)
totalSharesOutstanding = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", frequency, barmerge.gaps_on)
totalDebt = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "NET_DEBT", frequency, barmerge.gaps_on)
cashEquivalents = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "CASH_N_EQUIVALENTS", frequency, barmerge.gaps_on)
periodPrice = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)
marketCap =  totalSharesOutstanding * periodPrice

dilutionRatio = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, 'TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING', frequency, barmerge.gaps_on) / request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, 'DILUTED_SHARES_OUTSTANDING', frequency, barmerge.gaps_on)

//Daily FCF Yield
dailyFCF = (fcf / ((marketCap + totalDebt) - cashEquivalents)) * 100
plot(dailyFCF, style = plot.style_line)

// Free Cashflow yield
fcfYield = (fcf / ((marketCap + totalDebt) - cashEquivalents)) * 100
fcfYieldDiluted = if dilutionRatio <= 1 
    fcfYield * dilutionRatio
else 
    fcfYield

plot(fcfYield, "FCF Yield Net", color =  color.new(color.lime, 20), style =  plot.style_line, linewidth = 2)
plot(fcfYieldDiluted, "FCF Yield Diluted", color =  color.new(color.green, 60), style =  plot.style_area, linewidth = 3)

if fcfYieldDiluted > 0
    label.new(bar_index, fcfYieldDiluted, str.tostring(fcfYieldDiluted, format.percent), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white)

var lastYear = float(na)
var lastBar = int(na)
var last10Years = array.new<float>(10, na)
if not na(fcfYieldDiluted)
    log.info("{0}", fcfYieldDiluted)
    lastBar := bar_index
    lastYear := fcfYieldDiluted
    last10Years.push(fcfYieldDiluted)
    if (last10Years.size() > 10)
        last10Years.shift()

if barstate.islast
    log.info("log {0}, {1},", lastBar, last10Years)
    var last2YearsAvg = array.avg(last10Years.slice(last10Years.size() - 2, last10Years.size()))
    var last5YearsAvg = array.avg(last10Years.slice(last10Years.size() - 5, last10Years.size()))
    var last10YearsAvg = array.avg(last10Years)
    
    if not na(lastYear)
        var labelText = "Avg FCF Yield % Diluted" +"\n1Y: " + str.tostring(lastYear, format.percent) + "\n2Y: " + str.tostring(last2YearsAvg, format.percent) + "\n5Y: " + str.tostring(last5YearsAvg, format.percent) + "\n10Y: " + str.tostring(last10YearsAvg, format.percent)
        var xLoc = lastBar + math.round(1.2 * frequencyUnit)
        var yLoc = math.abs(lastYear * 0.9)
        label.new(xLoc, yLoc, labelText, style = label.style_label_left, color = color.green, textcolor = color.white)

